# PC for DMV knowledge test - since when?

Tags: history

I was watching a movie [License to Drive](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095519/) (1988) where the character was doing a DMV (Department of Motor Vehicles) knowledge test on an interactive software on a PC. I was a bit surprised that such tests may have existed back then, probably because what was then probably a high-tech solution in a conservative government body seems out of context. Such a solution may also hint to the use of a LAN (Large Area Network), which is even more surprising for that year.

My question is when did such tests actually start? The movie takes place in California.

Comment: LAN usually translates to *Local* Area Network* and in itself is neither new in 1988 or adding some new factor here - unless you could give an example why you're surprised about it.

Comment: I took a driving test in San Francisco in 2013. The knowledge test was on paper and inspected by a human being. So: still not yet in at least one of the populous areas of that state, at least if you're a grown-up making a regular appointment.

Comment: This seems to be more a question about a specific government agency's practices, than about retrocomputing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the rather broad question, even some serious old technology like Scantron and Mark-Sense fits.

Scantron based tests are in use by various DMV (*1) in the US since the 1970s. Even before that IBM Mark-Sense systems (*2) where used. So computer based licence tests handling is nothing new.

Similar terminal based solutions have been tried and used since the 1970s.

*1 - or whatever agancy takes/took the test in a state

*2 - Some may remember the system from school, where you had to usespecial pencils and make nice big graphite markings

Comment: I was referring to an interactive test on a pc (perhaps a terminal?) not a paper test that is later snalyzed by a machine.

Comment: Heck, when I got my license the test was administered on Scantron-like paper but the actual checking was done by the guy that owned the driving school, by hand, immediately after the test!  This was ca. 2010.